# Verifying a Recursion Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

[image]

I am attempting to prove the equation at the bottom of the image, or simply verify that it is a true mathematical relationship. I have computed a(3) and, in the latter part of the question, found the base case for using induction. (Note: I am only allowed to use inductive reasoning to prove this.)

Comment: I want to clarify that I have been able to prove the initial case for induction (as anyone should).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! First of all, I'm not sure what your question is asking... You've given a recursion, do you want to find a closed form? Asymptotics? What is $a_0$? Your question, as it stands, is somewhat unclear, and we can help you better once we understand what you're asking

Comment: Also, it's important to include some description of what you've already tried, you say you've done algebraic manipulations, but which ones? Why aren't they working? The more we know about what you're struggling with, the better we can help you.

Comment: I want to verify that this formula holds for n >= 0. In essence, I want to use induction to prove that this is true for n = 0, then for every n = k + 1, where k is >= 0.

Comment: One last reason to include a description of what you've tried is so that we know you've tried _something_. If your question looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you, it's not likely to be well received. Make sure we know that you've put some time and thought into the problem before coming here, and we'll be happy to help ^_^

Comment: I've tried ways of regrouping and multiplying by 1 in the form of a conjugate (i.e. 1+r).

Comment: What formula? You've only included one equation, so I assumed it was the _definition_ of $a_n$. If it isn't, then we need to know what $a_n$ is defined to be so that we can prove it equals what you've written above.

Comment: Totally understand that; I don't have any on-paper attempts since I've erased them all and re-attempted.

Comment: The definition of a(n) is the only formula given for the problem. It simply asks to "verify" that this is a true mathematical relationship.

Comment: I mean... if this is a definition, then it's true by definition... What is $d$? Maybe that will help me understand

Comment: Actually, see my above edit. The language of the full question is a tad vague, but there is another formula given for a(n).

Comment: If you have a picture of the original problem, maybe that will help too

Comment: d and r are real numbers.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the entire question. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This explains the question. I'll post an answer now with some hints

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel as though I've come close to proving it so many times but just haven't seen the relation I needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your background is, so I will try to be thorough in my description of what is happening. Know that I'm not trying to be patronizing at all, I just want to make sure that everything I say is clear.

First the question defines a sequence of real numbers $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ by 
referring to terms which came before. The definition says:

$$a_0 = 1$$

$$a_n = r a_{n-1} + d$$

Let's compute a few terms of our sequence, then:

$a_0 = 1$ is given to us. So that one's easy to compute.

$a_1$ is a bit harder. We know that $a_1 = r * a_{1-1} + d$ from the second equation, and so we can simplify

$$a_1 = r * a_0 + d = r * 1 + d = r+d$$

we are able to do this because we already know $a_0$!

Similarly, we can compute $a_2$ as follows:

$$a_2 = r * a_{2-1} + d = r * a_1 + d = r * (r + d) + d = r^2 + rd + d$$

so $a_2 = r^2 + rd + d$

Again, we are only able to do this because we already know $a_1$.

At this point, you should be equipped to solve the first part of the problem:

$$\text{compute $a_3$}$$

You know $a_2$, so by following the above pattern, you should be able to compute $a_3$ for yourself.

---

It's clear that, continuing in this manner, we can find $a_{17}$ eventually. Or $a_{150}$, or any $a_n$ we want. What is equally clear is that this process will take a very long time. Even if we get a computer to do it, this is a tedious process for large $n$. It's natural, then, to ask if there's a better way. Is there some formula which will just *tell us* $a_n$ without us having to compute $a_{n-1}$, which requires us to compute $a_{n-2}$, which requires us to compute $a_{n-3}$ and so on?

The problem is kind enough to *tell* us what $a_n$ is equal to. Instead of going through this exhausting process of building our way up from $a_0$, we can just plug $n$ into a formula:

$$a_n = r^n + \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}d$$

Let's check this on some small cases.

We know $a_0$ should be $1$. Let's check the formula:

$$a_0 = r^0 + \frac{1-r^0}{1-r}d = 1 + \frac{0}{1-r}d = 1$$

It works! What about $a_1$? Again, from the previous discussion we know it should be $r+d$.
What does the formula give?

$$a_1 = r^1 + \frac{1-r^1}{1-r}d = r + d$$

So far so good! Let's do $a_2$ together as well. We know it should be $r^2 + rd + d$. Indeed...

$$a_2 = r^2 + \frac{1-r^2}{1-r}d = r^2 + \frac{(1+r)(1-r)}{1-r}d = r^2 + (1+r)d = r^2 + rd + r$$

The formula seems to work! Now you can check your answer from before. You computed $a_3$ directly - does your answer agree with the answer the formula gives?

---

Of course, checking that the formula works for $n=0,1,2,3$ isn't enough to *know* that the formula works. We want to prove (with induction) that the formula *always* gives the same value as $a_n$.

Well, we can start with the base case: $a_0 = 1$, and the formula agrees!

Now let's do the inductive case. Say we know that $a_{n-1} = r^{n-1} + \frac{1 - r^{n-1}}{1-r}d$. Can we show that $a_n = r^n + \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}d$?

Well, let's see:

$$a_n = r a_{n-1} + d$$

thankfully we have an expression for $a_{n-1}$ lying around (this is our *Inductive Hypothesis*): let's substitute it in.

$$a_n = r (r^{n-1} + \frac{1-r^{n-1}}{1-r}d) + d$$

We can simplify this a little:

$$a_n = r^n + \frac{r (1-r^{n-1})}{1-r}d + d = r^n + \frac{r - r^n}{1-r}d + d$$

Now, ideally, we would be able to show that this expression is equal to 
$r^n + \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}d$. I'll leave it to you for now, but I suggest factoring out the $d$ in the first expression. From there it's some simple algebra to get it to look like what you want it to look like. Good luck!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks so much! I had a form similar to this earlier where I had a d/(1-r) and I was combining the fractions, but it never occurred to me to simplify it like this!

Comment: awesome! I'm glad I could help ^_^ If this answered your question, you should accept it so that others on the site know how to spend their time

Comment: I was just about to! :)

Answer (score 0):

*A small trick*

Considering
$$a_n = r\, a_{n-1} + d$$ let $a_n=b_n+k$ and replace
$$b_n+k=r \, b_{n-1}+ r k +d$$

So, make
$$k=rk +d \implies k=\frac d {1-r}$$ and you are left with the simple
$$b_n=r \, b_{n-1} $$ When solved for $b_n$, go back to $a_n=b_n+\frac d {1-r}$